# Inner class AsyncTask using method in surrounding Activity class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Something that puzzles me since months. Is the following construct save? AsyncTask is an inner class in an Activity. AsyncTask calls a method within the Activity class. This method does not use activity objects or UI calls.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(...) {
            longRunningMethod();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(... ) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute (...) {
        }
    }

    private void longRunningMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, that's why I've written that this method does not do UI calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe if not updates the UI, if you're updating the UI you can use runOnUiThread method.

Comment: Thanks. So when the activity dies (orientation change for example) and the thread is running it can still use that method?

Answer (score 0):

its safe as long as it does not try to modify the UI.